# Is Ionic V4 support android version less than 7.0?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I have created Ionic app in V4. App load fine but some plugin like camera and Razor pay crash the app and reload whole app with splash screen.

I just wanted to know that is Ionic V4 support android older version?

Comment: try remove platform and add it again then create new build

Answer (score 0):

Ionic use cordova to build android apps. First you should check which version of cordova are you using.

Latest version of Cordova is 8.X.X

Cordova 8 support from android **4.4 to 9.0.0**

For more information:
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/index.html